# Multiple likes in Laravel database command

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have a field called 'Amenities' in a MySQL table. The contents of the column I am querying looks like this

```
a:4:{i:123;s:3:"123";i:126;s:3:"126";i:127;s:3:"127";i:133;s:3:"133";}
```

And a dropdown that is styled as below -

[image: Amenities dropdown]

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Amenities</label>
        <select class="form-control select2" name="amenities" multiple="multiple">
            <option value="123">Garden</option>
            <option value="124">Garage</option>
            <option value="125">Furnished</option>
            <option value="126">Unfurnished</option>
            <option value="127">Driveway</option>
        </select>
</div>
```

I am trying to query based on the values selected using the following code -

```
if($request->amenities){
        $ads = $ads->where('amenities','like', "%{$request->amenities}%");
}
```

It works for the first amenity selected but not if I select multiple amenities. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Fundamentally, your data shouldn't be stored like this. You can use the `JSON` type for the column, which will allow you to query against it. You could also have an `amenities` table and a `property_amenities` pivot table that allows you to use a proper set of Laravel relationships.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass a two-dimensionnal array to `where()`, each entry will represent a condition:

```
$conditions = [];
foreach ($request->amenities as $amenity){
    $conditions[] = ['amenities', 'like', '%'.$amenity.'%'];
}
$ads = $ads->where($conditions);
```

Comment: I'd note that this will break if, say, `12` is entered, as it'll match `123`, `1234`, `9201293`, etc. Fundamentally, this data should be stored as distinct rows in a pivot table or as a native JSON data type in the database so it can be properly queried.

Comment: @ceejayoz then he should change "LIKE" to "=" and remove the wildcards to avoid this.

Comment: That won't work either, as the wildcards won't work anymore.

Comment: (and `='123'` will never match data like `a:4:{i:123;s:3:"123";}`)